# Eclipse update fails

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

i try to update my Eclipse software but i get:

```
    Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/umlet-uml-tool-fast-uml-diagrams#.U1YM7_l_tuB.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/umlet-uml-tool-fast-uml-diagrams#.U1YM7_l_tuB is not a valid repository location.
No repository found at http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html.
No repository found at https://github.com/caprica/vlcj.
No repository found at jar:file:/C:/Users//Downloads/com.umlet.plugin_12.2.0.jar!/.
Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=43220.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=43220 is not a valid repository location.
No repository found at jar:file:/C:/Users//eUML2-studio-Edition-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update site configuration is broken.

Go to "Window/Preferences/Install/Update/Available Software Sites" and uncheck every item there.

[image: Available Software Sites configuration]